# Trouble in adding a column with awk

Tags: text-processing, awk, columns

I'm trying to add a column to a csv file by using:

```
awk -F "," '{print $0"new_col"}' file.csv
```

but I got :

```
new_col8,0.405,0.101
new_col4,0.374,0.100
new_col23,0.342,0.100
new_col130,0.298,0.100
```

instead of :

```
68,110,0.362,0.101,new_col
11,98,0.405,0.101,new_col
57,94,0.374,0.100,new_col
61,123,0.342,0.100,new_col
124,130,0.298,0.100,new_col
```

I tried like this too:

```
awk -F "," '{{$(NF+1)=",new_col"} print $0 }' file.csv
```

but i got the same result!!!

Is someone already had this problem?

Comment: awk -F , '{print $0 ",new_col"}' file.csv just works on me. Can you try it? And just awk '{print $0 ",new_col"}' file.csv seem to work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `.csv` is in DOS format another option might be:

```
tr -d \\r <input.csv | sed 's/$/,new_col/'
```

...which would handle it all in one shot.

Answer (score 3):

Your input `csv` file is in DOS format.  Microsoft DOS/Windows use a Carriage Return (`\r`, `^M`, ASCII code 13) followed by a Line Feed (`\n`, `^J` or ASCII code 10) at the end of each line while Linux/Unix uses the Line feed only.

To fix this, run:

```
$ dos2unix file.csv
dos2unix: converting file file.csv to Unix format ... 
$ awk '{print $0",new_col"}' file.csv
```

Note the comma before `new_col`. Without it, `print` concatenates `new_col` directly onto the end of `$0`. There is no need to signify the field seperator (`-F`) because you are not splitting the input line into fields - you are only using `$0`.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work? `awk -F, '{$(NF+1)="new_col";}1' OFS=, input.txt`.

This will output the new table in command line. In the example, I've added an output file (`output.csv` just in case).

Before running the command:

```
$ cat input.csv
68,110,0.362,0.101
11,98,0.405,0.101
57,94,0.374,0.100
61,123,0.342,0.100
124,130,0.298,0.100
```

Executing the command:

```
$ awk -F, '{$(NF+1)="new_col";}1' OFS=, input.csv > output.csv
```

Checking output file:

```
$ cat output.csv
68,110,0.362,0.101,new_col
11,98,0.405,0.101,new_col
57,94,0.374,0.100,new_col
61,123,0.342,0.100,new_col
124,130,0.298,0.100,new_col
```

[Example page](http://www.theunixschool.com/2012/11/awk-examples-insert-remove-update-fields.html)